# Assign a server as leader in zookeeper ensemble

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We have a quorum of 4 servers which has zookeeper 3.4.6 installed in all of them.The leader election is currently managed automatically. However we would like to assign a particular server as a leader as this box is more robust and has high capabilities.
  I am looking for a setting to assign a server as leader always.Is it possible?. I even tried the zookeeper 3.5.1-alpha version but even that doesnt seem to have any particular setting. I understand there are algorithms for implementing the election but a setting will be more advantageous for us.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 0):

There is no such setting. Leader election is automatic unless you decide to implement an algorithm but seems to me thats not a solution you are looking for.